# docker-compose run multiple times in parallel with different project names but without rebuilding

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose

In our Jenkins CI we are running our end2end integration tests in parallel (using 3 docker-compose run-commands). The separation works by having separate project names to each call assigned, however that results in all container become rebuild-ed (as their project names are different). Is there way to avoid that?

So what we actually need:

- build multiple containers defined in docker-compose file
- run the set of containers multiple times but completely separated - **without rebuilding** and **with full separation**

We are doing basically this:

- `docker-compose build` <- this builds all containers under the default project name
- `docker-compose run container command_1 -p project_1` <- this re-builds all containers as no containers with the project name "project_1" exists.
- `docker-compose run container command_2 -p project_2` <- as this is done in parallel, it also rebuilds
- `docker-compose run container command_3 -p project_3` <- as this is done in parallel, it also rebuilds

Here is basically our docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=foo
      - POSTGRES_USER=foo
      - POSTGRES_DB=foo_test
  backend:
    build:
      context: ../backend
      dockerfile: .docker/Dockerfile
    command: /workspace/.docker/start_end2end.sh
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
    volumes:
      - ./e2e.env:/.env
  cypress:
      ipc: host
      build: 
        context: ../tests
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      volumes:
        - ../tests/cypress:/app/code/cypress
      depends_on:
        - backend
        - frontend
      environment:
        - CYPRESS_baseUrl=http://frontend:4200
        - CYPRESS_defaultCommandTimeout=10000
        - CYPRESS_RETRIES=3
        - NO_COLOR=1
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ../frontend
      dockerfile: .docker/Dockerfile
    command: /workspace/.docker/start_end2end.sh
    depends_on:
      - backend
    environment:
      - BACKEND_HOST=backend
```

And this is the relevant part from the Jenkinsfile:

```
stage('Building containers') {
    steps {
        sh "docker-compose -f ./shared/docker-compose.yml -f ./tests/docker-compose.override.yml build"
    }
}
parallel {
    stage('End2End Tests 1') {
        steps {
            sh "docker-compose -f ./shared/docker-compose.yml -f ./tests/docker-compose.override.yml -p ${env.JOB_NAME}_${env.BUILD_ID}_1 run --rm cypress npm run end2end:1"
        }
    }
    stage('End2End Tests 2') {
        steps {
            sh "docker-compose -f ./shared/docker-compose.yml -f ./tests/docker-compose.override.yml -p ${env.JOB_NAME}_${env.BUILD_ID}_2 run --rm cypress npm run end2end:2"
        }
    }
    stage('End2End Tests 3') {
        steps {
            sh "docker-compose -f ./shared/docker-compose.yml -f ./tests/docker-compose.override.yml -p ${env.JOB_NAME}_${env.BUILD_ID}_3 run --rm cypress npm run end2end:3"
        }
    }
}
```

I was not able to archive what I describe above, only:

- Don't use different project names -> no rebuilding on multiple parallel calls. But the depending containers are shared.
- Do use different project names -> rebuilding on multiple parallel calls. The containers are not shared.

Comment: Is the rebuild actually taking any time?  Normally, if you ask Docker to rebuild an image but the Dockerfile and the `COPY`ed files are identical, you do technically get a new image but it entirely comes from Docker's build cache, and it takes almost no time and almost no additional space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified in the [docker compose file reference for the `build` section](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#build)

> If you specify `image` as well as `build`, then Compose names the built image with the `webapp` and optional `tag` specified in `image`:
>
> ```yaml
> build: ./dir
> image: webapp:tag
> ```

So something like below will always build images for all services with the same names regardless of the current project name and use those images by default when calling `docker-compose up` if they already exist.

```yaml
services:
  service1:
    image: my_service1:1.0.0
    build:
      context: ../service1
      dockerfile: .docker/Dockerfile
  service2:
      image: my_service2:1.0.0
      build: 
        context: ../service2
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
  service3:
      image: my_service3:1.0.0
      build:
        context: ../service3
        dockerfile: path/to/another/Dockerfile
```

This example can later be extended to you own needs (e.g. by passing the tag in an environment file...)

Comment: That's a promising solution, thanks! Will try it out and report back.